# How to get custom attribute using PHP Simple HTML Dom?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have tags with custom attributes in my HTML

```
...
<img alt='test' width='20' height='20' title='test' loadlater='path_to_img.png' />
...
```

When I load my code using `str_get_html` everything works fine. I can navigate trough DOM, I can search, ... But when I read attributes from image tag

```
foreach($data->find("img") as $_img) {
    print_r($_img->attr);
}
```

I only get valid HTML attributes (alt, title, width, height). Attribute `loadlater` is missing.

Did anyone manage to parser custom attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Looks fin for me.

```
<?php
require_once "./vendor/autoload.php";

$str = "<img alt=\'test\' width=\'20\' height=\'20\' title=\'test\' loadlater=\'path_to_img.png\' />";

$dom = \Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser::str_get_html( $str );

foreach($dom->find("img") as $_img) {
    print_r($_img->attr);
}
```

results with

```
Array
(
    [alt] => \'test\'
    [width] => \'20\'
    [height] => \'20\'
    [title] => \'test\'
    [loadlater] => \'path_to_img.png\'
)
```

composer:

```
"require": {
    "sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser": "v1.5.0"
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I use this class:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

I will definitely try suggested and switch if everything is OK!

Comment: Hmm... it usese the same functions ... They just added class before this file... For me it stil doesn't work which is pretty strange.

Comment: Yes, it is just a wrapper to install the library with composer. It works with php 5.5, libxml 2.9. What is your versions? Also what is the exact output for the snippet in the answer?

Comment: The problem was special chars inside loadlater attribute. I simply cut out data and present it as text and than it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<img alt='test' width='20' height='20' title='test' loadlater='path_to_img.png' />
EOF;

$dom = str_get_html($html);

echo $dom->find('img', 0)->loadlater;
```